# What's the intuition behind MIP* being bigger than MIP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, interactive-proof-systems

It is well-known that $\mathsf{MIP} = \mathsf{NEXPTIME}$, and recently there was a breakthrough stating that $\mathsf{MIP^*} = \mathsf{RE}$.

This was very confusing because it seemed like the (malicious) provers should become more powerful about fooling the verifier, for the provers was equipped with a new toy, namely quantum entanglement.

My intuition was this: Since quantum entanglement cannot be used for communication anyway, the correlation is actually *restricting* what the provers observe.

Still, if that's the case, couldn't the provers simply *ignore* what the toy gives?

Comment: https://medium.com/mit-6-s089-intro-to-quantum-computing/mip-re-6e903720c82f